# How can I extend autocomplete's source in the course of geocoding

Tags: jquery-ui, google-maps, autocomplete, geocoding

I create an autocomplete field [like that](http://tech.cibul.net/geocode-with-google-maps-api-v3/) for the Google Maps. It's working, but I need to extend the address list with my own points (specifically with [category](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#categories)). The autocomplete function's **source** option needs the extending:

```
  gc = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  $(Element).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      gc.geocode( {'address': request.term }, function(results, status) {
        response($.map(results, function(item) {
          return {
            label:  item.formatted_address,
            value: item.formatted_address,
            latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
            longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
          }
        }))
      })
    },
    select: ...
  });
```

Any idea? Thank you in anticipation

Comment: So you need the category functionality you linked to plus what you have here?